# Bot framework passing the values to bot ... How to receive them in the Bot C# code

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework

I am passing the token and userid from the direct line web channel. I want to know How to receive those values in Bot side to show the userid or email passed from the direct line channel.

```
<html>
<div id="webchat" role="main" />
<head>
<script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/webchat.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
  window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
      directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ token: '@Model.Token' }),
        userID: '@Model.UserId'
  }, 
  document.getElementById('webchat'));
</script>
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: Please make sure to make my reply as answer if it had helped you ,so others can make use of it.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a store like below and add c custom data channelData , i have used [simpleUpdatein](https://unpkg.com/simple-update-in/dist/simple-update-in.production.min.js) Package for it

```
const store = window.WebChat.createStore(
            {},
            ({ dispatch }) => next => action => {
                if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/POST_ACTIVITY') {
                    action = window.simpleUpdateIn(action, ['payload', 'activity', 'channelData', 'myData'], () => myDataObj);
                } 
                return next(action);
            }
        );
```

Then inject this store to directline instance like

```
window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
            directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({
                token:  '@Model.Token', 
            }),
            userID: '@Model.UserId'
            store, 
        }, document.getElementById('webchat'));
```

Now in Bot side you can access it under context object ,full path below

```
dialogContext.Context.Activity.ChannelData
```

You can also take a look at this [Sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/04.api/b.piggy-back-on-outgoing-activities)for more info